# SQL not showing updated tables

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm working with a MySQL database which is constantly updating (adding new values and removing old ones).

From a client computer I connect to the database using the python MySQL client, the first time I connect I can fetch the data at the current point but when I make the query again the data retrieved doesn't change despite the database has been updated.

**Initialization code:**

```
self.idb=MySQLdb.connect(host=xxx,user=xxx,passwd=xxx)
    self.ic=self.idb.cursor()
    self.ic.execute('SHOW DATABASES')        
    options=sorted([x[0] for x in self.ic.fetchall() if x[0].startswith('xxx')],reverse=True)
    self.ic.execute('USE {}'.format(options[0]))
```

**Query:**

```
self.dbi=pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM RawData', con=self.idb)
```

From the server I can verify that the data is constantly updating.

Can the updated data be retrieved without having to close the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the default isolation level, **Repeatable Read**, you need to make a **COMMIT** in the transaction you are so the rest of the users can see the changes you have made. And yes, you can make a **COMMIT** without closing the DB. You could use:

```
self.ic.commit()
```

You should read the [Mysql Isolation Levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) to get more information about how they work and how to change them.